# Format of ESAPI encode in an output with DecimalFormat

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, owasp

I'm currently working through several forms with outputs to the user and I've successfully applied the `#esapiEncoder.encodeForHTML()#` without issue thus far but I'm thrown as to whether this is the correct way of typing out an encode when `DecimalFormat` is part of it.

```
#esapiEncoder.encodeForHTML(DecimalFormat(hrsTotalLeave))#
```

Would that be the correct method? Or is it:

```
#DecimalFomat(esapiEncoder.encodeForHTML(hrsTotalleave))#
```

This page is using ColdFusion if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to encode your values at the outermost level, so `#esapiEncoder.encodeForHTML(DecimalFormat(hrsTotalLeave))#` would be the way to go.

Using your second example and attempting to use format functions on encoded strings will potentially lead to issues as well.

Comment: To make sure I did a few tests and I'd make you right on this one. I also did a test with MonthAsString and it only displays correctly on the first format.

Comment: Yes, I believe that you will run into issues trying to use a format function on encoded strings. I will include that in the answer as well.